# How to make a C ++ console automatically in SublimeText3?

Tags: c++, windows-10, sublimetext3

I decided to program in Sublime Text3 in C ++. When I compile the program, Sublime Text3 does not open the console for me, but leaves it to me as a separate file on the desktop. How can I make sure that after compiling the program, Sublime will automatically display the data input console for me (I have Windows 10).

Comment: How is this a C++ related Stackoverflow question? This seems more like a question that should be pointed at Sublime support forums..

Comment: You question is entirely unclear but there's no such thing as a `data input console` in Sublime; unless you install some third party package like `Terminus`, interactive programs will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a better approach to compile and run the code with your input. 
See the "[Sublime Input](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Input)" package.

Your code will be something like:

```
/*input
5
*/
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    cout << val;
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
5
```

Comment: Please see See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)",
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
and "[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a [sublime build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) that opens a cmd shell and runs your executable in that shell. So something along these lines:

```
{
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
    "shell_cmd": "cmd /k myexecutable.exe"
}
```